# How to order the citation by appearance using amsplain?

Tags: amsplain

The bib style needs to be amsplain. Below is the minimum code. The complied text is:

> First citation [2]. Second citation [3]. Third citation [1].

How to the change it by appearance, so the order is [1], [2], [3] in the text? Thanks.

Main file:

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}
First citation \cite{Smith1978}. Second citation \cite{yu2012}. Third citation \cite{Heywood1988}.

\bibliographystyle{amsplain}
\bibliography{bibFile.bib}

\end{document}
```

Bib file:

```
@article{yu2012,
  title={Extended smoothed boundary method for solving partial differential equations with general boundary conditions on complex boundaries},
  author={Yu, Hui-Chia and Chen, Hsun-Yi and Thornton, K},
  journal={Modelling and Simulation in Materials Science and Engineering},
  volume={20},
  number={7},
  pages={075008},
  year={2012},
  publisher={IOP Publishing}
}

@article{Heywood1988,
author = {Heywood, John B},
chapter = {1},
isbn = {007028637X},
journal = {Internal Combustion Engine Fundamentals},
mendeley-groups = {0paper},
pages = {1--37},
publisher = {McGraw-Hill College},
title = {{Engine Types and Their Operation}},
year = {1988}
}

@book{Smith1978,
author = {Smith, A.F. and Hales, R.},
pages = {246},
publisher = {Taylor and Francis},
title = {Werkstoff und Korrosion},
year = {1978}
}
```

Comment: You can't use `amsplain`, then, because it sorts by author. The AMS doesn't provide for unsorted bibliographies. And if you're requested to use `amsplain`, then they want sorted bibliographies.

Comment: The AMS recommendation used to be (and may still be) to use `unsrt` if no sorting is wanted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no way to use `amsplain` to sort by appearance. `amsplain` is a style which sorts entries alphabetically by definition. See [this link](https://www.math.uh.edu/%7Etorok/math_6298/latex/bibtex.html) for an explanation on different bibtex styles and [this link](https://www.cs.stir.ac.uk/%7Ekjt/software/latex/showbst.html) for examples and results of different styles.

A good way to find out more about the use of bibtex is their own webpage, http://www.bibtex.org/

As mentioned by egreg, if they ask you to use amsplain, they want it to be sorted alphabetically.